# Isomorphism of canonical rings and arithmetic genus.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

Suppose you have two integral Gorenstein projective curves $X$ and $Y$ over a field, and suppose further that we have an isomorphism  $$\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty H^0(X,\omega_X^{\otimes n}) \cong \bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty H^0(Y,\omega_Y^{\otimes n}) $$ of canonical rings. Can we then conclude that $X$ and $Y$ has the same arithmetic genus?

I think this is easy, it is claimed at the end of section 2.3 in the paper [*Fourier-Mukai partners of singular genus one curves*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.1318.pdf). For some reason this isn't clear to me.

Comment: Hint: look at duality for schemes of dimension 1 plus the definition of arithmetic genus via Euler characteristic.

Comment: Oh boy that was easy....I should have another cup of coffee in the mornings. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: @KReiser You should post as an answer so others don't keep looking at the question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: look at duality for schemes of dimension 1 plus the definition of arithmetic genus via Euler characteristic.